# Use of Fork-Join in Verilog

Tags: task, fork, verilog

I would like to do a task that checks in parallel one of the two statements commented below and that doesn't break the execution of the program that follows it:
The Task checks if startTx has been generated. It must wait for startTx signal 5 clock cycles. If the startTx is asserted, it prints a successful message. If not (after the timeout), it prints an error message and increases the error counter.

What I've done so far is:

```
    task checkStart;
      begin
      fork
    // evento 1
        begin
          waitCycles(5); // timeOut
          $display("[Error! %t] Time Out has been reached", $time);
          errors = errors + 1;
        end
    // evento 2
        begin 
          @(posedge(startTx))
          $display("[Info] startTx has been generated successfully"); 
        end
      join
      disable fork; 
      end
    endtask
```

But doesn't seem to be working as it apparently checks for both statements to be true and I would like something as 'join_any' from SystemVerilog that breaks whenever one of both statements become true.

Comment: I use Verilog with Modelsim, but apparently it doesn't allow to use neither join_none nor join_any I don't know why..

Comment: Probably join_any is part of systemVerilog but not Verilog 2005.  Try renaming your file <file>.sv rather than <file>.v

Comment: But if one of my design constraints is to must use a verilog file (.v), is there something similar to join_any in Verilog or perhaps is that code should be written in another way to have that effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works without using the SystemVerilog join_any.  Comment startTx or uncomment it to see the two conditions that occur.

```
module tb ();

  bit SIGNAL;
  bit startTx;

  int errors;
  
  task checkStart;
    fork
      // evento 1
      begin  : timeout
      #500; // timeOut
      $display("[Error! %t] Time Out has been reached", $time);
      errors = errors + 1;
      $finish;
      end
    // evento 2
    begin  :wait_for_signal
      @(posedge(startTx))
      $display("[Info] startTx has been generated successfully"); 
      disable timeout;
    end
     //
    join
    //  
    $display("+++++ Finished checkStart ++++++");
  endtask  
        
initial
 begin
   checkStart();
    // Do something else
    #20;
    $display("**** normal finish ****");
    $finish;   
 end
  
initial
  begin
    #1;
    // coment one of these at a time
    //startTx = 1;
    startTx = 0;
  end

endmodule
```